# equality of two objects depending on conditions.

Tags: logic

I want to state that two objects $t_i, t_j$ are equal if some conditions hold. Can this be done by writing: $t_i = t_j \rightarrow$ some conditions?

Comment: The arrow is facing the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of such a condition is the axiom of extensionality found in most set theories. It states that if $x$ and $y$ have exactly the same members, then $x=y$. Symbolically, $\forall x \forall y(\forall z(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y)\to x=y)$. Note why you don't need the conditional in the other direction: if $x=y$ then by the rules of first order logic anything you say of $x$ must be true of $y$ and vice versa.

EDIT: It occurred to me I could make this more informative by considering the case where the antecedent is $x=y$ with different things predicated of $x$ and $y$. Say we have two predicates $P(-)$ and $Q(-)$ and a formula of the form $x=y\to(P(x)\wedge Q(y))$. An obvious instance of this is $x=x\to(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$, so that the formula reduces to $\forall x(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$.